# Converting Float to String Causing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, floating-point, nullpointerexception, touch-event

I am trying to display the float value "degrees" as a string in a TextView on my layout, but receive a NullPointerException on tv.setText(mydegrees);  I have tried numerous methods to convert the float to a usable string value, but can't seem to get the TextView to display the float value.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: The degrees is manipulated by an onTouchEvent

TextView from XML:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/current_degrees"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
android:text="@string/app_name"
android:textColor="#FFFF00" />
```

Java Code:

```
float degrees = (float) -65;
String mydegrees = String.format("%.2f", degrees) ;

//...

public void pushClick(View pushClick) {
    switch (pushClick.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_push:

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_degrees);
        tv.setText(mydegrees);
```

Comment: That looks like tv is `null` and has nothing to do with your degrees string.

Comment: Your problem (whatever it is -- you don't say) has nothing to do with converting float to string.

Comment: After reviewing the xml code, I did find a typo with id of the TextView that caused the problem as I was using a similarly named TextView later in the same layout for testing.  Fixing the typo resolved the NPE.

Comment: Sorry, it was in a different layout, not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: As `@Jake King` noted, in my previous answer I was not paying attention to the details (that your `mydegree` member is a `String` instance.

This way the only reason for you to get a `NPE` is that your `tv TextView` is null.

Please check your layout xml file you use for the activity / renderer / view, and make sure you have there a `TextView` or any extension of it with `@+id/current_degrees`.

Also, your title is very misleading: If you have your `float` declared and initialized as above, then there cannot be any `NullPointerException`.

Comment: you're right `@Jake King`, I missed it. thanks for noting, i'll change my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As tigrang points out, your problem is not converting a float to a String. What you have should work fine. Your problem is that `findViewById()` is returning a `null` value for some reason or another, presumably because no views have the ID you provided. Make sure the ID is correct and that you are getting a valid `TextView` instance before attempting to perform any operations on it.

Comment: As stated above I found the issue with a typo in the TextView id and have made the correct.  Without realizing it, I had already used the same 'current_degrees' id in a different layout which is why I was able to map the TextView to that id without an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
String degreesStr = Float.parseFloat(degrees);
```

try this which converts a float value to string.

Answer (score -1):

Simple.. use this

```
tv.setText(degrees+""); //Degrees is the float value
```